# change the view when switching to a new tab - c++, MFC visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, tabs, mfc

I have a program that has two tabs when run and it looks like this:

[image]

The problem is I would like to show new static text when I click on "Item 2" tab like this: 
[image]

How do I do this? I'm currently using Visual Studio 2013 and C++. I been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEN1j1waN-8.  Here is my code:

```
// MFCApplication1Dlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MFCApplication1.h"
#include "MFCApplication1Dlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialogEx(CAboutDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CMFCApplication1Dlg dialog



CMFCApplication1Dlg::CMFCApplication1Dlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CMFCApplication1Dlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CMFCApplication1Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TAB1, m_MyTabCtrl);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCApplication1Dlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    //ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_EDIT1, &CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnEnChangeEdit1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CMFCApplication1Dlg message handlers

BOOL CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here

    m_MyTabCtrl.InsertItem(0, _T("Item 1"));
    m_MyTabCtrl.InsertItem(1, _T("Item 2"));

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}



void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnEnChangeEdit1()
{
    // TODO:  If this is a RICHEDIT control, the control will not
    // send this notification unless you override the CDialogEx::OnInitDialog()
    // function and call CRichEditCtrl().SetEventMask()
    // with the ENM_CHANGE flag ORed into the mask.

    // TODO:  Add your control notification handler code here
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyyskx80.aspx
You basiclly need to handle the WM_NOTIFY coming from the tab control in the parent window.

Comment: thanks Jonathan, I wonder if  is there any specific example or tutorial that shows how to handle WM_NOTIFY

Comment: http://computer-programming-forum.com/82-mfc/0202244ace04fdfd.htm
look at  ON_NOTIFY(TCN_SELCHANGE, IDC_TAB, OnSelchangeTab)

Answer (score 1):

You can handle ON_NOTIFY(TCN_SELCHANGE, IDC_TAB, OnSelChangeTab)

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyTabbedDialog, CDialog)
    ON_NOTIFY(TCN_SELCHANGE, IDC_TAB, OnSelchangeTab)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void MyTabbedDialog::OnSelchangeTab(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{

    UpdateVisibleWindow();

    *pResult = 0;
}

void MyTabbedDialog::UpdateVisibleWindow()
{
    int current = m_myTab.GetCurSel();

    MyFirstDialog.ShowWindow(current == 0 ? SW_SHOW : SW_HIDE);
    MySecondDialog.ShowWindow(current == 1 ? SW_SHOW : SW_HIDE);
}
```